# What sentence should I use when I want to know if what I explained was understood or not?

Tags: phrases

I explained something in English, for example about the history of my hometown, without any preparation. I'm not sure if they understood what I said or not.
In order to make sure, which sentence should I use? I think that "Do you understand it?" sounds very rude, because the problem is my English. How about "Did I make myself understood?" Does it make sense? Could you tell me the polite sentences I can use in these situations?

Comment: You can always say "Was my English clear?" or "Was my explanation understandable?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try:

> Did that make sense?

or

> Did I say that correctly?

Both of these statements put the focus on the correctness of your speech, rather than any implication of the listener's inability to understand.

Your initial example of *Did I make myself understood?* is perfectly acceptable English and means what you want to say, but sounds a bit more formal. You're probably better off with one of the first two sentences, but you'd be understood if you said that.

Comment: Thank you.  Then, can I also say,"Does that make sense?"?

Comment: @tennisgirl Yes, you certainly can! You can say either "did" or "does", it doesn't make a practical difference.

Comment: Does "Did I say that correctly?" ask if I was understood? I could be understood with my broken English, even if I didn't say something correctly, especially if I say the same wrong phrase over and over, and it is now clear what I mean when I use it. It probably depends from the person, and from the moment, but I can imagine the answer to be "I understood what you mean." "I understood what you mean, but [explanation of what I didn't say correctly]." "I am not sure I understood you; did you mean […]?"

Answer (score 0):

How about

> Did I make myself understandable?

I'm just taking on the sentence logically.

"Did I make myself understood?" >> "Yes, you made yourself (or your speech) understood". That sounds like you, not your audience, understood.

"Did I make myself understandable?" >> "Yes, you (or your speech) are understandable". This just make a little more sense to me.